# segfault with gcc4.9.1 when working with std::complex<double>

Tags: c++, c++11, segmentation-fault, complex-numbers

I am getting a segfault when trying to run the following tiny piece of code (compiled with gcc4.9.1 macports OS X 10.10 Yosemite):

```
#include <complex>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::complex<double> z{1,0}; // 1 + i
    std::cout << z << std::endl; // segfault here, why ?!?!?
}
```

The program compiles and runs fine on any other compiler (clang, previous g++ versions etc) except g++4.9.1. I am completely puzzled, can anyone reproduce the segfault? It is extremely bothersome for me as my whole project is using complex numbers, and everything ceased working (i.e. segfaulting) after I start using g++4.9.1. The above code is the minimal example I could come up with. I am not using any optimization flags, just plain `g++ -std=c++11 test.cpp`. It looks like a compiler bug, but I am not sure.

Comment: Can you post the actual message or does it only say "Segmentation fault"?

Comment: It just says `Segmentation fault: 11`

Comment: What happens if you try to compile the program with `clang++ -stdlib=libstdc++`?

Comment: Just did that, and it works, doesn't segfaults, I am completely puzzled

Comment: When you do `clang++ -stdlib=libstdc++ -std=c++11 test.cpp -v`, which version of GCC is it using?

Comment: Yeah it doesn't use the one from macports, it uses `/usr/include/c++/4.2.1`, so probably that's why `libstdc++` is not broken there

Comment: Just wondering, is there a member function of std::ostream or a general overload of the << operator for std::complex or even a conversion function that I am unaware of?

Comment: It seems to be related to macports implementation of libstdc++ for g++4.9.1, as I tested now under Ubuntu 14.04 (g++4.9.1), and it doesn't produce the segfault under Ubuntu.

Comment: @Veritas the `<<` is overloaded for std::complex and produces output like (1,0)

Comment: After a lost Sunday, I realized that probably the overloaded operator `ostream& operator<<(...)` for `std::complex` has an issue for `std::complex`. The complex number itself is initialized ok, I can print out (using `ostream`, i.e. `cout << z.real() << z.imag() `) the real and imaginary part, however when I try to use `<<` it fails with a segfault.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone bumps into this issue, here is the answer. It was a bug in `libgcc`, see the bug I've filled https://trac.macports.org/ticket/45483 , which has now been fixed, so you may want to upgrade/update your macports installation.